# Sort objects in order as they appear in the outliner

Tags: python

I have a collection of objects named 'test0', 'test2'...'test999'.

When copying these objects between different Blender scenes/windows sometimes the internal collection order gets messed up and `bpy.data.objects[0].name` yields 'test11' (only an example, not sure of the pattern) instead of 'test0'.

But visual order in the outliner stays the same.
Am I missing an easy way to get the order of the collection in the outliner? The info seems to be there.

Sorting alphabetically doesn't work either and outputs 'test1', 'test10'...
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no reliable way to ensure the order in which objects are stored in `bpy.data.objects`. In my experience, saving / loading and using the undo system can mess up the order.

You should **never, ever** rely on accessing objects by index in `bpy.data.objects`, unless you have a very specific workflow and even then I think you should use a workaround like custom properties, etc.

Objects are uniquely defined by their name in `bpy.data.objects`, and that's the only built-in way you can uniquely identify them with the API. The container acts like a dictionary AND a list since objects can be accessed by name and by index but I wouldn't ever use the latter if I want a reliable system.

Objects are (by default) ordered alphabetically in the outliner, that's why they stay ordered when copy/pasting.

You can get the objects ordered alphabetically with :

`objects = sorted(bpy.data.objects[:], key=lambda obj: obj.name)`

Comment: Bummer. Tried obj.name with sorted(), but order is like this then 'test0', 'test1', 'test10'. Alphabetically in outliner is different.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your outliner to your question ?

Comment: Objects are sorted using [BLI_strcasecmp_natrual](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/460f7ec7aacf23f391dacd7839c8c160679ad62d/source/blender/blenlib/intern/string.c#L730) but I don't know if you can call it from Python. Also see [outliner_tree.cc](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/460f7ec7aacf23f391dacd7839c8c160679ad62d/source/blender/editors/space_outliner/outliner_tree.cc#L967).

Comment: Interesting. Surely someone somewhere has translated it to python. :)